# cross reference nearest date data

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I have three table `ElecUser`, `ElecUsage`, `ElecEmissionFactor`
`ElecUser:
 UserID  UserName
 1       Main Building
 2       Staff Quarter`

`ElecUsage:
 UserID Time      Amount
 1      1/7/2010  23230
 1      8/10/2011 34340
 1      8/1/2011  34300
 1      2/3/2012  43430
 1      4/2/2013  43560
 1      3/2/2014  44540
 2      3/6/2014  44000`

`ElecEmissionFactor:
 Time        CO2Emission 
 1/1/2010    0.5
 1/1/2011    0.55
 1/1/2012    0.56
 1/1/2013    0.57`

And intended outcome:
`UserName    Time       CO2
 1           2010       11615
 1           2011       37752 (34340*0.55 + 34300*0.55)
 1           2012       24320.8 
 1           2013       24829.2
 1           2014       25387.8
 2           2014       25080`

The logic is ElecUsage.Amount * ElecEmissionFactor.
If same user and same year, add them up for the record of that year.
My query is:
`SELECT  ElecUser.UserName, Year([ElecUsage].[Time]), SUM((ElecEmissionFactor.CO2Emission*ElecUsage.Amount)) As CO2
FROM ElecEmissionFactor, ElecUser INNER JOIN ElecUsage ON ElecUser.UserID = ElecUsage.UserID
WHERE (((Year([ElecUsage].[Time]))>=Year([ElecEmissionFactor].[Time])))
GROUP BY ElecUser.UserName, Year([ElecUsage].[Time])
HAVING Year([ElecUsage].[Time]) = Max(Year(ElecEmissionFactor.Time));`

However, this only shows the year with emission factor.
The challenge is to reference the year without emission factor to the latest year with emission factor.
Sub-query may be one of the solutions but i fail to do so.
I got stuck for a while. Hope to see your reply.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this..

-- not tested

```
select T1.id, year(T1.time) as Time, sum(T1.amount*T2.co2emission) as CO2 
from ElecUsage T1 
left outer join ElecEmissionFactor T2 on (year(T1.time) = year(T2.time))
Group by year(T1.time), T1.id
```

use sub query to get the corresponding factor in this way

```
    select T1.id, 
        year(T1.time) as Time, 
        sum(T1.amount*
                    (
                    select top 1 CO2Emission from ElecEmissionFactor T2 
                    where year(T2.time) <= year(T1.time) order by T2.time desc
                    )
        ) as CO2 
from ElecUsage T1 
Group by year(T1.time), T1.id
```

Comment: didnt read 'The challenge is to reference the year without emission factor to the latest year with emission factor' .. give me a min

Comment: Man, I gotta say i really appreciate your so so quick response. That works like a magic. I kept thinking of using max(). You gave a good insight of using order.

Comment: Hope you see this or i would ask a new question. I am using access to generate graph. The intended result is reached with three column. But when i try to generate a broken line graph, access prompts ElecUsage.Time not recognized as valid field

Comment: HI, I am not so sure about access, please post a new question.