# MS access broken line chart prompts unrecognized field

Tags: ms-access, charts, ms-access-2013

This is to create a broken line graph about a query.
`select T1.id, 
        year(T1.time) as Time, 
        sum(T1.amount*
                    (
                    select top 1 CO2Emission from ElecEmissionFactor T2 
                    where year(T2.time) <= year(T1.time) order by T2.time desc
                    )
        ) as CO2 
from ElecUsage T1 
Group by year(T1.time), T1.id`
detailed discussion is here:[cross reference nearest date data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31529235/cross-reference-nearest-date-data)
The query works fine and shows desired result.
It is with three column,`UserName`, `Year`, `CO2`
However, when i try to make a chart using:
TRANSFORM Sum([CO2]) AS [Total CO2] SELECT [Year] FROM [test] GROUP BY [Year] PIVOT [UserName];
Y axis: CO2
X axis: Year e.g. 2010, 2011
Legend: user name

Access prompts ElecUsage.Time unrecognized field

How come it is ok with query but not chart?
Thanks for any reply
_______________________________________________
I tried not to put all three elements on the chart and it would be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporary / alternative solution.
Alter the query to create table for the result of query.
Then create chart based on the table.